# Query unread Messages by a User in a Chat

Tags: mysql, laravel, filter, eloquent, chat

I'm trying to build a query that is getting hard...
I'm developing a Chat app in Laravel, with simple structure:

- A Chat hasMany messages.
- And each Message belongsTo an User.
- n:m between Users and Messages to save read Messages.

So

**Chat.php**

```
public function messages() {
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class)
}
```

**Message.php**

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function reads() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'reads');
}
```

**User.php**

```
public function messages() {
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
}

public function reads() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Message::class, 'reads');
}
```

well, now I want the next query

> Give me all Chats that has Messages unread by me (logged user)

That means something like this:

```
Chat::whereDoesntHave('messages.reads', function (Builder $q) {
            return $q->where('user_id', auth()->id());
        });
```

Buts thats not working because if Chat has a single Message read by me, it gets ignored :(

Maybe I could achieve this by scoping to the **LAST** Message of the Chat only? Or maybe could I make an operation like this:

- Count all Chat Messages
- Count all Chat Messages read by Me
- Make a subtraction, if not 0, consider this Chat :D

But I don't know how to do that 'operation' with Eloquent.

Please, help.
Thanks!

Comment: Why you need to store seened messages in a different table ? Isn't it easy to add `is_read` field to messages table. Thus all you have to do is just creating a scope to get unread messages

Comment: Because each Message can get read by multiple different Users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finnaly found the way to fetch only last message of the Chat and check if this one has been read by an specific user, usig a Query Builder approach.

Here I post the magic scope, using sub queries ;)

```
public function scopeUnreadBy(Builder $builder, int $userId)
{
    //First, look for Chats with Messages
    return $builder->whereHas('messages', function (Builder $q) use ($userId) { 
        $q->select(['last_message' => function(\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $sub) {
            // Then, take only last one Message
            $sub->select('id')
                ->from('messages')
                ->where('chat_id', 'chats.id')
                ->latest()
                ->limit(1);
        }])->whereDoesntHave('reads', function(Builder $q) use ($userId) {
            // Finally, check that last one has not been read :D
            return $q->where('user_id', $userId);
        });
    });
}
```

Phew, that was hard.

I hope it helps to someone else!

And remember, all can be done with one single query ;)

Answer (score 0):

first pluck id of all chat that read by you.

```
$pluckedId=Chat::has('messages.reads', function (Builder $q) {
            return $q->where('user_id', auth()->id());
        })->pluck('id');
```

Then apply

```
Chat::whereNotIn('id', $pluckedId )->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, that works but I need a query builder approach to apply filters dynamically with scopes. I'm sure it can work with something like subqueries.